# fsockopen ssl connection not working

Tags: php, openssl, fsockopen

I'm trying to use php function fsockopen on a smtp server using ssl on port 465 on my local server with apache.
It works well with php command line but I get a SSL error when the script is running in my browser.

php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll line is not commented
```

phpinfo through Apache

```
Loaded Configuration File : D:\localhost\php-5.4.11\php.ini
openssl
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
```

phpinfo with command line

```
Loaded Configuration File => D:\localhost\php-5.4.11\php.ini
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
```

My script

```php
$smtp = fsockopen('ssl://in.mailjet.com', 465, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$response = fgets($smtp, 4096);
if(empty($smtp)){
   echo $response;
   return false;
}
echo $response . '<br/>';
fclose($smtp);
```

Output under apache

```
Warning: fsockopen(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout in XXX on line 2
Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in XXX on line 2
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://in.mailjet.com:465 (Unknown error) in XXX on line 2
```

Output with command line

```
220 srv12.mailjet.com ESMTP Mailjet
<br/>
```

Platform: I'm using PHP 5.4.11 / Apache 2.2.22 (Win32) on Windows 8 64

-- Edit --
I've tried using TLS as suggested:

```php
$smtp = fsockopen('tls://in.mailjet.com', 567, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

And I get

```
E_WARNING: fsockopen(): in XXX on line XXX
```

Error message is blank and `$errno = (int) 0` and `$errstr = (string) ''`

Comment: You may want to look at using a library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead of rolling your own SMTP client. However, try using the `tls://` wrapper instead of `ssl://`. If that doesn't work, try connecting using the `tcp://` wrapper and manually enabling crypto on the stream with `stream_socket_enable_crypto()`. The error message says there is a timeout occurring - how long after you start the script do you get the error message (i.e. how long is the timeout?)

Comment: I've tried with this : `code` fsockopen('tls://in.mailjet.com', 567, $errno, $errstr, 30); `code` and I get E_WARNING: fsockopen(): in XXX on line XXX

Comment: You get a blank error message?

Comment: @DaveRandom the timeout is 30 seconds as specified in the 5th argument of fsockopen. I reduced it down to 5 seconds as the script is fast in CLI version, and I get the error about 5 seconds after refreshing the page in my browser. I try your tip with tcp:// wrapper and come back with feedbacks

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes I get a blank error message which is confusing. Arguments 3rd and 4th return : $errno = (int) 0 and $errstr = (string) ''

Comment: @DaveRandom SwiftMailer does not work too

Comment: I've just throw this simple test script together to hopefully help nail the problem down, can you run it and see what happens? http://pastebin.com/rin9Y0By

Comment: @DaveRandom
SSLv2:

Connecting...
Error: Unable to enable encryption on the connection: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout
SSLv3:

Connecting...
Error: Unable to enable encryption on the connection: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout
SSLv2/3:

Connecting...
Error: Unable to enable encryption on the connection: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout
TLS:

Connecting...
Error: Unable to enable encryption on the connection: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout

Comment: @DaveRandom command line works for sslv3, sslv2/3 and tls. It alos seems to be more precise on the error for sslv2 : Error: Unable to enable encryption on the connection: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1406D0B8:SSL routines:GET_SERVER_HELLO:no cipher list

Comment: Try adding `stream_context_set_option($this->socket, 'ssl', 'ciphers', 'ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL'); stream_context_set_option($this->socket, 'ssl', 'no_ticket', true);` on line 126 of the code in the pastebin.

Comment: You can also try `stream_context_set_option($this->socket, 'ssl', 'ciphers', 'RC4-SHA');` although this would not be ideal because it limits your code to using that specific cipher. However a couple of people on the internetz suggest this may be a "fix".

Comment: @DaveRandom Your first suggestion gives same result. The second one about RC4-SHA creates a new error: Unable to enable encryption on the connection: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): failed to create an SSL handle

Comment: Can you give more information about your Apache build? Are you using a package like XAMPP or are you using separate builds? Are you using mod_php or fcgid?

Comment: I've installed Apache, PHP and MySQL all by myself. I think I'm using php-cgi as I have this line in my httpd.conf: "Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php-cgi.exe"", I can't find "mod_php" in my httpd.conf and phpinfo gives me "Server API: CGI/FastCGI" Apache version is 2.2.22

Comment: @DaveRandom here is my phpinfo content if it helps: http://pastebin.com/bhmVgWMf

Comment: Can you try updating to the latest PHP stable release (5.4.13)? This is built against a later version of OpenSSL (0.9.8y). If this doesn't work then the problem most likely lies somewhere in your Apache install. Also it might be an idea to update Apache to the latest stable (2.4.4), as the 2.4 branch provides a number general improvements. There's nothing immediately obviously wrong from your configuration file so I'm wondering if it may be simply a bad build of php-cgi.exe. The CLI uses a different binary which may explain the differing behaviour using the same configuration.

Comment: @DaveRandom I was thinking about updating too. I'll do it later and keep you informed. Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: @DaveRandom I've updating earlier this morning my Apache version and the problem is now solved. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my Apache version from 2.2 to 2.4 and it works now.

I've followed this tutoriel : http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/ to get the new Apache version.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with a contact form which uses captcha, getting the error

```
fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://mail.google.com:443
```

This is on a FreeBSD vm, with Joomla installed.

Searching, I found http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php which mentioned certificate validation.

Installed the FreeBSD port `ca_root_nss` which includes certificate validation for Root certificates from certificate authorities included in the Mozilla NSS library.